# Is a CMS based on HTML stored in variables in js files, loaded dynamically feasible

Tags: javascript, html

I have been working on a concept that uses a single host client page that loads **js files dynamically on demand**, that contains variables such as

```
var newt = "<span style='color:red;'>This is a new test</span>";
```

that are injected into the page via `innerHTML`.

There is no database and no PHP is required to load the page. Very simple protype works - any thoughts on this concept? Has it been tried before?

This is the dynamic js load script

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype) 
{
    if (filetype=="js") //if filename is a external JavaScript file
    { 
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
    {
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
    }
}
```

Comment: Storing dynamic data in javascript files doesn't make any sense. The idea of any kind of content management is based around storing data in a database where it is flexible and relational, which requires a server-side implementation. Storing anything to a js file would require a server-side implentation anyway, but databases are much more feature rich.

Comment: Sure, but want to find an elegant, fast system with no db and minimal php - could be faster and more efficient, perchance? Many CMS use xml files, text files, no DB. This method stores HTML and injects it into the page without reloading the whole page.

Comment: XML and text files? I guarantee you those are not good CMS. I'm building a CMS with the core concept that there shouldn't be page reloads. This is accomplished properly using standard JavaScript Single Page App techniques (history api w/ hashbangs for older browsers) and a RESTful api server-side implentation for serving data to the JavaScript.

Comment: GetSimple CMS works well using XML files. Thanks for the info on Single page - I'll check it out.

Comment: There are definitely limitations with a CMS like that. Typically "CMS" refers to something more powerful. I would call that a "light" cms. In that case, there are plenty of simple things that can be done. I think storing data as JSON's is much more ideal than XML. Anyway, what you really need to do before implementing  a cms is have a strong understanding of general principles such as Object Oriented Programming, relational (and non-relational) data systems and security.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford jQuery, you can use its [getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method. I use it in several cases for lazy loading script files.

An even more advanced technique in this topic is to use the [requireJs](http://requirejs.org/) component, which is designed for dynamic script loading on demand.